# why multi_gpu_model in tf.keras is much slower than the one in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, multi-gpu

The multi_gpu_model in tf.keras seems to be much slower than the one in keras. For the example given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/multi_gpu_model), it is about 12x slower when importing from tensorflow.keras instead of keras.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import Xception
from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import numpy as np

num_samples = 1000
height = 224
width = 224
num_classes = 1000

# Instantiate the base model (or "template" model).
# We recommend doing this with under a CPU device scope,
# so that the model's weights are hosted on CPU memory.
# Otherwise they may end up hosted on a GPU, which would
# complicate weight sharing.
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = Xception(weights=None,
                     input_shape=(height, width, 3),
                     classes=num_classes)

# Replicates the model on 8 GPUs.
# This assumes that your machine has 8 available GPUs.
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)
parallel_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='rmsprop')

# Generate dummy data.
x = np.random.random((num_samples, height, width, 3))
y = np.random.random((num_samples, num_classes))

# This `fit` call will be distributed on 8 GPUs.
# Since the batch size is 256, each GPU will process 32 samples.
parallel_model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=256)

# Save model via the template model (which shares the same weights):
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

The only changes are

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import Xception
from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
```

instead of

```
from keras.applications import Xception
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
```

With tf.keras

```
Epoch 1/20
```

1000/1000 [==============================] - 78s 78ms/step - loss: 3487.2197
Epoch 2/20
1000/1000 [==============================] - 37s 37ms/step - loss: 3454.2403
Epoch 3/20
1000/1000 [==============================] - 37s 37ms/step - loss: 3453.6264
Epoch 4/20
1000/1000 [==============================] - 37s 37ms/step - loss: 3452.7994
Epoch 5/20
1000/1000 [==============================] - 37s 37ms/step - loss: 3452.3592

Importing directly from keras

```
Epoch 1/20
```

1000/1000 [==============================] - 52s 52ms/step - loss: 3486.8955
Epoch 2/20
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 3454.1935
Epoch 3/20
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 3453.5585
Epoch 4/20
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 3452.8249
Epoch 5/20
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 3452.1542

That is like a 12x speed difference from the second epoch onwards.
I am using latest keras 2.2.4 and tensorflow-gpu-1.10

Comment: As far as I know, not all models take advantage of multi GPU. However, it's not your case, you're comparing the same model for both. But, just in case, could you repeat the same test with a different model?

Comment: Before i tested the Xception model from keras, i was trying to figure out why my own model is very slow when switching from keras to tf.keras. So these are two examples. It maybe related to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23077